# If current text data = any other text data then...?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check if the current clicked text has the same data as any other text on the page as the below text is put on the page twice. Once the text has be clicked it will add a class (this bit is working) and if it also has the same data as any other text on the page then that text will also be given the new class.

```
<span class="AJAXPagerSpan" data-num="6">6</span>
<span class="AJAXPagerSpan" data-num="12">12</span>
<span class="AJAXPagerSpan" data-num="24">24</span>  



  $(".AJAXPagerSpan").click(function() {
        <%= this.ID %>_Pager.ChangeResultsPerPage($(this).html()); 


       // Check if any of its siblings are part of the "highlightclass" and remove them from it
        $(this).siblings().removeClass("highlightclass");
        if ($(this).data() == $(this).siblings().data()) {
        $(this).addClass("highlightclass");
        };
       // Add it to the highlightclass
        $(this).addClass("highlightclass");

  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".AJAXPagerSpan").click(function () {
    $(".highlightclass").removeClass("highlightclass");
    $("span[data-num=" + $(this).data("num") + "]").addClass("highlightclass");
});
```

Your code has the following problems:

1. You were missing the argument to `.data()` to specify the name of the data.
2. You were missing parentheses around the `if` condition.
3. You need to test each sibling separately. When used with a collection, `.data()` just returns the value from the first element of the collection. You could have used a `.each()` loop.

Rather than looping, I used a selector that matches the data attribute.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/L4wLb/6/)

Comment: None of your elements have the same data.

Comment: I may not have the same data in the siblings. Any way I can check the entire page for the ceratin data-num value

Comment: I got rid of `siblings` and just used a general selector for all spans with the data-num value.

Comment: That works great now however the matching text that was found keeps the class no matter what I do. I need the remove class to also work. Thanks for all your help

Comment: Just match everything with the highlightclass and remove it.